# looping image ie7 issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to create an infinitely scrolling image in a div using javascript with jquery. The code I'm using can be seen in the fiddle [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XaSHa/3/).

This works in current browsers, but fails in IE7. My guess is that it has something to do with assigning negative css values, but I have yet to find a solution. Does anyone know how to get the behaviour seen in chrome in ie7?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
I have gotten the effect working cross-browser *if* I scroll the image vertically moving downward. Can be seen [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XaSHa/6/).

EDIT 2:
I have gotten it working horizontally, but only moving to the right. It seems to dislike the negative direction value. Can be seen [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XaSHa/9/).

Comment: Have you tried debugging at all?

Comment: I am working on this issue right now, I'll certainly update the question if I come across any new info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think IE7 is only supporting Integer values for the 'left'-property!

change your function to:

```
$(function(){
reelDivs($('.reel div'), 'left', 500, -500, -1, 30);
});
```

Comment: Its not the negative number as you supposed its the Float instead of Integer! you got it working because you used 1 instead of 0.1 and a higher timeout!

Comment: You champion. Thanks! Working fiddle using Nikolaj's solution if anyone is interested http://jsfiddle.net/XaSHa/14/

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to this and give it a go:

```
.reel
{
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.reel div
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    height: 362px;
    width: 500px;
    background: url("http://www.deviantart.com/download/258376230/husky_puppy_by_blackdelive-d49twdi.png") no-repeat 0px top;
}

.reel div.b
{
    left: 500px;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eGnMX/

God-speed!

Comment: This fiddle doesn't seem to be working in ie7. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Put an ID on the reel div and instead of using `$('.reel div')` use the ID. I'm pretty sure IE7 don't support `getElementsByClassName`.

When you use `$('.reel div')` you're telling jQuery to use getElementsByClassName.

Comment: This is why he's using jQuery. Irrelevant of IE7 this selector would work.

Comment: Hm, I can't tell how jQuery works behind the curtains. If it does what you're saying, so my idea would still be great for performance though.

Comment: jQuery handles all the browser compatibility behind the scenes. It's possibly one of its biggest advantages! Performance wise though, yes, ID's will always be fetched much faster.

Comment: Rep+ thanks for that info. I forget sometimes how jQuery is so efficient. If it wasn't the Java lookalike, no performance but excelent usability.

Answer (score 0):

How do you move an image 0.1 pixels, considering a pixel is the smallest size your monitor can render?

IE7 will not support floating point measures as far as im aware (or at least not on pixels, haven't tested other units). Console log the returned CSS left position and you will see IE7 does not return a floating point number.

Use 1 pixel movements and decrease the redraw rate to get it working in IE7. Or even better play with the pixel movement vs rate to get the desired result. The higher the pixel movement the better.

Redrawing an image can be expensive on the visitors machine. Even if you were exclusively creating something for a gaming community (who generally have fast, high end systems), i wouldn't recommend making it an absolute requirement. Your image scroller alone could seriously lag some systems out there.

Also dont forget most monitors won't have a lower refresh rate than 5ms. So expecting it to re-draw quicker than that is pointless